# Specific data to Excel with Convtool

Tags: python, excel

**Good evening!**

I am trying to export JSON data that I have selected with Selenium (Pre-tag) to a CSV file. I want to specify specific data and transform it to CSV. To select different type of data, I am using **Convtool** and convert it.

**For example, this is the whole JSON code from page:**

```
{"getUrl":"/395012/Organization/pase11469","className":"Organization","data":{"name":"Förskola Garphyttan","organizationNumber":"212000-1967","centralPhoneNumber":{"value":"019-215030","normalized":"+4619215030","className":"PhoneNumber","isEmpty":false},"faxPhoneNumber":{"value":null,"normalized":null,"className":"PhoneNumber","isEmpty":true},"website":"www.orebro.se","email":{"value":"","className":"Email"},"dateLastModified":"\/Date(-62135596800000)\/","visitAddress":{"street":"Kilsvägen 2 B","zipCode":"719 40","city":"GARPHYTTAN","countryCode":""},"postalAddress":{"street":"Kilsvägen 2 B","zipCode":"719 40","city":"GARPHYTTAN","countryCode":""},"responsibleCoworker":null,"integrationid":null,"customFields":[],"relation":0,"tags":null,"headOffice":{"id":"pase276386","getUrl":"/395012/Organization/pase276386","className":"Organization","heading":"Örebro kommun","subHeading":"Örebro","categorization":null,"isDeleted":false},"corporateGroup":{"id":"pase276386","getUrl":"/395012/Organization/pase276386","className":"Organization","heading":"Örebro kommun","subHeading":"Örebro","categorization":null,"isDeleted":false},"sharedBody":{"vatNumber":"SE212000196701","lineOfBusiness":"Förskoleutbildning","businessDescription":null,"legalForm":"Kommun","dateOfRegistration":"1975-07-01","legalName":"Örebro kommun","rating":null,"numberOfSubsidaries":2,"numberOfEmployeesRange":">10000","numberOfEmployeesWorkSite":"10 - 19","dividends":null,"employeeGrowth":null,"equityRatio":null,"quickRatio":null,"resultBeforeTax":null,"salariesBoardMembers":null,"salariesOthers":null,"turnoverGrowth":null,"turnover":null,"numberOfEmployees":null,"averageSalaryPerEmployee":null,"turnoverPerEmployee":null,"profitMargin":null,"resultAfterFinancialItems":null,"ebita":null},"temperature":0},"actions":{"getHistory":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/getHistory","getFuture":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/getFuture","getDocuments":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/getDocuments","getEmployees":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/getEmployees","getDeals":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/getDeals","addFileForm":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/addFileForm","addFile":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/addFile","addLink":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/addLink","update":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/update","setResponsibleCoworker":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/setResponsibleCoworker","follow":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/follow","setRelation":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/setRelation","getSuggestedPersons":"/395012/SuggestedPersons/pase11469/getForOrganization","searchEmployees":"/395012/OrganizationSearch/pase11469/employees","getEmployeeTemplate":"/395012/Person/GetTemplate?employerId=pase11469","addToTargetList":"/395012/targetAppender/appendOrganization?organizationId=pase11469","addTag":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/addTag","removeTag":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/removeTag","getUnassignedTags":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/getUnassignedTags","addNewTag":"/395012/Organization/pase11469/addNewTag","createTodo":"/395012/todo/create?organizationId=pase11469","getMeetingTemplate":"/395012/Meeting/getTemplate?OrganizationId=pase11469"},"id":"pase11469","heading":"Förskola Garphyttan","subHeading":"Garphyttan","source":{"data":{},"conflicts":null},"whoIsHere":[],"isTouched":false,"isFollowing":false,"errors":null,"categorization":["branchoffice","subsidiary"],"relatedCategorizations":{"/395012/Organization/pase276386":["headoffice","corporategroup"]}}
```

**When I am printing it out after I have converted it:**

```
    [[{'f_namn': 'Two Cents AB', 'org_nr': '556424-4381', 'Phone Number': None}]]
[[{'f_namn': 'Two Cents AB', 'org_nr': '556424-4381', 'Phone Number': None}], [{'f_namn': 'Förskola Garphyttan', 'org_nr': '212000-1967', 'Phone Number': '+4619215030'}]]
```

**When I am trying to run my code I receive this error:**

```
File "c:\Users\Tobias\Projects\Lime-GO\Lime-GO.py", line 98, in find_company
    xd = pd.json_normalize(prepared_data)
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 270, in _json_normalize
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
  File "C:\Users\Tobias\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\json\_normalize.py", line 270, in <genexpr>
    if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

It is working when I am skipping the converter and just export all data to Excel, but there is no structure and I do not need all information.

**My PY Code:**

```
lst = []
        for k in range(11468, 11470, 1):
            link = baseLink + str(k)
            self.driver.get(link)

            # Convert what I want
            converter = c.list_comp(
                {
                    "f_namn": c.item("data", "name"),
                    "org_nr": c.item("data", "organizationNumber"),
                    "Phone Number": c.item("data", "centralPhoneNumber", "normalized"),
                }
            ).gen_converter()  # install "black" to see formatted sources

            res = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre").text
            lst.append(converter([json.loads(res)]))

            prepared_data = lst
            xd = pd.json_normalize(prepared_data)
            xd.to_excel("list.xlsx", index=False, sheet_name="Sheet2")
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you've wrapped the data with a list excessively.
Also I'd suggest you split your code into meaningful pieces.

```py
import json
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from convtools import conversion as c


class YourClassName:
    base_link = "your base link goes here"

    def fetch_page(self, k):
        url = urljoin(self.base_link, str(k))
        print(f"getting {url}")
        self.driver.get(url)
        # TODO: handle when there's no element
        # add waiting code
        element = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre")
        return element and element.text

    def iter_pages(self):
        for k in range(11468, 11470, 1):
            data = self.fetch_page(k)
            if data is None:
                print(f"failed to load page #{k}, skipping")
                continue
            yield json.loads(data)

    def fetch_all(self):
        # you can move this out of the class
        convert = c.list_comp(
            {
                "f_namn": c.item("data", "name"),
                "org_nr": c.item("data", "organizationNumber"),
                "Phone Number": c.item(
                    "data", "centralPhoneNumber", "normalized"
                ),
            }
        ).gen_converter()  # install "black" to see formatted sources
        data = convert(self.iter_pages())
        return data

    def dump_to_xlsx(self):
        # your to_excel code goes here


YourClassName().fetch_all()
```